# SQLite : ORDER BY a joined column

Tags: java, join, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have this simple request :

```
SELECT *
FROM categories 
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON categories.id = items.category_id 
ORDER BY items.category_id, items.name;
```

The problem is that the results are ordered following **items.id**, instead of the two specified columns.

If I replace with :

```
ORDER BY categories.id, items.name;
```

It works great, but it doesn't use my index:

```
CREATE INDEX items_index ON items(category_id, name);
```

How can I resolve that properly? Thank You.

**Edit :** Here is how I created the 2 tables :

```
// Categories
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE categories (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "parent_id INTEGER , " +
            "resource_name TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);");

db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX categories_index ON categories(parent_id);");

// Items
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE items (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "category_id INTEGER , " +
            "name TEXT, " +
            "price REAL, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);");

db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX items_index ON items(category_id, name);");
```

How I insert the categories :

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id", category.getId());
    values.put("parent_id", category.getParentId());
    values.put("resource_name", category.getResourceName());

    db.insert("categories", null, values);
```

And the items :

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("category_id", item.getCategoryId());
    values.put("name", item.getName());
    values.put("price", item.getPrice());

    long id = db.insert("items", null, values);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is ignored"? Can you provide a complete minimal example, i.e. the `create table` statements along with a few `insert`s?

Comment: @redneb By "is ignored" I mean that the results are ordered following the primary key, instead of the specified column. I'm afraid that SQLite does not allow the right table columns in the ORDER BY part, unlike MySQL. Did you hear one thing about that?

Comment: I've used `ORDER BY` many times before like that with `sqlite` and it definitely works. Try to come up with a minimal and complete example as I asked above.

Comment: You aren't, just by chance, using this as a subquery?

Comment: No I'm not using a subquery. @redneb, I'm happy to know that it works with you, it gave me hope :). I came up with more code. Thanks.

Comment: @Denis Your code above looks fine. We will not be able to help you unless you also provide some sample data. Try to find the smallest set of rows possible that cause the problem. For example, take your data set and start slowly removing rows until there only few of them left (ideally just a handful of rows for both tables). Make sure that the problem persists with the remaining rows and post here the insert statements so that we can try it out. Remember that you can easily produce the list of the insert statements using the .dump command of the sqlite3 command line tool.